# How can I make cookies secure (https-only) by default in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, cookies, https, ruby-on-rails-5

In a Rails controller, I can set a cookie like this:

```
cookies[:foo] = "bar"
```

And specify that the "secure" (https-only) flag be on like this:

```
cookies[:foo, :secure => true] = "bar"
```

`:secure` is false by default. How can I have cookies be secure by default, application-wide?

This is on Rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @knx, you sent me down the right path. Here's the monkeypatch I came up with, which seems to be working:

```
class ActionController::Response
  def set_cookie_with_security(key, value)
    value = { :value => value } if Hash != value.class
    value[:secure] = true
    set_cookie_without_security(key, value)
  end
  alias_method_chain :set_cookie, :security
end
```

What do you think?

Comment: John, where in Rails app do we place the class above?

Comment: great. thank you. one more thing, i my dev env - using webrick - when i set the secure flag to true in environment.rb i cannot get passed my login screen - i noticed there is set cookie from app in responses. any idea what could be going one?

Comment: if you set the secure flag to true on your cookie, then the cookie won't be sent for non-https requests. are you using https in your dev environment?

Comment: i did set the secure flag to true on my cookie (through ActionController::Base.session). i set up apache httpd with ssl which forwards to WebRick in my dev env and still get same behavior

Comment: For anyone trying this on Rails 3.2.x, I believe set_cookie has been refactored in to ActionDispatch::Response so monkeypatching that class instead should work.

Answer (score 53):

There's no need to monkeypatch `ActionController`/`ActionDispatch`, and `force_ssl` has side effects (e.g. when [behind an ELB](http://scottwb.com/blog/2013/02/06/always-on-https-with-rails-behind-an-elb/)).

The most straightforward way to achieve secure cookies is to modify `config/initializers/session_store.rb`:

```ruby
MyApp::Application.config.session_store( 
  :cookie_store, 
  key: '_my_app_session',
  secure: Rails.env.production?
)
```

Comment: This is the right answer (verified that this works in Rails 4.2.7.1). To test this easily, set `secure: true` and then you can verify the cookie is generated correctly. Then you can change it back to `Rails.env.production?`

Comment: it looks like this will only affect the session cookie. The asking person requested secure as the default for all cookies. Can @david-cain verify whether that solution works for all cookies?

Answer (score 19):

starting with rails 3.1, according to [the rails security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-hijacking), you can simply set the following in your `application.rb`:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

this forces the cookie to be sent over https only (and I assume everything else, too).

Comment: This confused me at first: The *main* purpose of `config.force_ssl` is to only allow the rails app to work over SSL, but it *also* enables the `secure` flag on cookies. Before you set this config make sure you're okay with the rest of its effects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676596/what-does-force-ssl-do-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution: i think it is possible by modifying []= method in action pack cookies module (actionpack/lib/action_controller/cookies.rb)

from:

```
    def []=(name, options)
      if options.is_a?(Hash)
        options = options.inject({}) { |options, pair| options[pair.first.to_s] = pair.last; options }
        options["name"] = name.to_s
      else
        options = { "name" => name.to_s, "value" => options }
      end

      set_cookie(options)
    end
```

to:

```
    def []=(name, options)
      if options.is_a?(Hash)
        options.merge!({:secure => true})
        options = options.inject({}) { |options, pair| options[pair.first.to_s] = pair.last; options }
        options["name"] = name.to_s
      else
        options = { "name" => name.to_s, "value" => options }
      end

      set_cookie(options)
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# session only available over HTTPS
ActionController::Base.session_options[:secure] = true
```

Comment: is this a new feature in rails 4?

Comment: I dont know. However, in Rails 4 it works. You can also check this property in YOUR version of Rails.

Comment: This is for the session cookie only, right? Not for cookies in general?

Comment: It doesn't work in Rails 4.1 : `undefined method 'session_options' for ActionController::Base:Class (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Where to put this?

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/SessionManagement/ClassMethods/session_options

This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The last existing version (v2.3.8) is shown here.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the rack-ssl-enforcer gem. I was just looking for a clean answer to this and it solves the problem independent of which version of Rails you're on, plus it's extremely configurable.

Comment: Or the `secure_cookies` gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as mentioned in some of the above answers (use `secure` option in the `config/initializers/session_store.rb` file):

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_app_session',
                                                       secure: Rails.env.production?
```

which will only secure the session cookie, but other cookies will not be secure.

If you want to secure all the cookies in your Rails app by default, you can use the [secure_headers](https://github.com/github/secure_headers) gem. Just add the `secure_headers` gem to your Gemfile, `bundle install` the gem and create a `config/initializers/secure_headers.rb` file with this content:

```
SecureHeaders::Configuration.default do |config|
  config.cookies = {
    secure: true, # mark all cookies as "Secure"
  }
end
```

This will make all the cookies secure in your Rails app by default.

You can also add these recommended configurations and set the `httponly` and `samesite` options as well:

```
SecureHeaders::Configuration.default do |config|
  config.cookies = {
    secure: true, # mark all cookies as "Secure"
    httponly: true, # mark all cookies as "HttpOnly"
    samesite: {
      lax: true # mark all cookies as SameSite=lax
    }
  }
end
```