# Set secure session Cookie in Rails 2

Tags: ruby, session, cookies, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a Rails 2 application. And I want to set the session cookie to secure. By default it will be http only.To implement the same, I added the :secure=> true in config/initializers/session_store.rb as below:

```
ActionController::Base.session = {
  :key         => '_app_session',
  :secret      => '123.......',  
  :secure      => true
}
```

But it does not work. However, the same thing works well in Rails 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make cookies secure (https-only) by default in rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773605/how-can-i-make-cookies-secure-https-only-by-default-in-rails)

Comment: @lcguida: thanks for the link of possible duplicate question. However in that, none of them works for Rails 2 application.

Comment: @vipulKumar Secure cookies are https only. So it may only work when you access the application with a HTTPS url. What exactly "does not work"?

Comment: @nvugteveen: My application has https url only. I want my 'session' cookie to be secure. If I do the configurations as above, it does not make my session cookie secure. However the same configuration makes the cookie secure in Rails 3/4

Comment: @vipulKumar What do you mean by "secure"? Are you trying to prevent tampering, or trying to prevent users from reading the contents of the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the past. In config/environment.rb:

```
config.action_controller.session = {
  :session_key => '_app_session',
  :secret      => '123.......',
  :secure      => true
}
```